# Is it possible to compile a Qt+QML+OpenCV application for android

Tags: android, qt, qml, qt-necessitas

I have an application in my windows 7 which is written **using Qt + QML** and **OpenCV**. Now I'm wondering whether it is possible to compile it *using necessitas* project for **android** or not? I think I won't have problem with Qt+QML part of the project but is it possible to link a library(statically or dynamically) like opencv?I think I have to recompile the libraries for android! Am I right?
Do I have alternatives to compile this project for android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do that. Qt/QML seems to be quite good with necessitas, only some little changes might be necessary, but nothing impossible. I've done a couple of porting myself and I always got to the target quite fast. You sure can link to other libraries, and maybe necessitas also provides a way to do that simply: there might be something to work on (http://sourceforge.net/p/necessitas/tickets/106/) but you should succeed.

OpenCV on the other hand must be recompiled for Android yes. Anyway, I'm not an expert but I remember it has very few dependencies, so you should succeed on that as well. Also consider reading this: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#native-c. That porting might also be done already.